# How to render a different view in controller action of ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

How to render a different view other than default in controller action. by default it try to find the same view as action in the view folder but I would like render different view available in views folder for controler action.

We can do this ZF1 like this `$this->_helper->viewRenderer('foo');`

Can Anyone know, how to achieve above in Zendframework 2?

We can disabled the view using

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $response->setContent("Hello World");
        return $response;
```

I don't know how to change/render a different view in zf2.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

can be done using

```
public function abcAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel(array('variable'=>$value));
    $view->setTemplate('module/controler/action.phtml'); // path to phtml file under view folder
    return $view;
}
```

Thanks to [akrabat](http://zf2test.akrabat.com/) for covering almost every scenario.

Comment: https://github.com/akrabat/ZF2TestApp/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L78

Comment: Now how can we access the 'variable' value in view?

Comment: We can directly access using the $varibale variable in view - Thanks

Comment: Just to note you don't need to add the .phtml suffix, simply module/controler/action will also work

Answer (score 2):

My solution in Zend Framewor 2 is simple. For **index** action i prefer to call **parrent::indexAction()** constructor bcs we extend **Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController** . Or just **return array()** in indexAction. ZF will atomaticly return index.pthml whitout definig what must be returned.

**return new ViewManager()** is the same **return array()**

```
<?php

 namespace Test\Controller;

 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController,
     Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

 // Or if u write Restful web service then use RestfulController
 // use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController

 class TestController extends AbstractActionController
 {
    /*
     * Index action
     *
     * @return main index.phtml
     */

     public function indexAction()
     {
          parent::indexAction();

          // or return new ViewModel();
          // or much simple return array();
     }

    /*
     * Add new comment
     *
     * @return addComment.phtml
     */

     public function addAction()
     {
         $view = new ViewManager();
         $view->setTemplate('test/test/addComment.phtml');  // module/Test/view/test/test/

      return $view;
     }
```

Dont forget to configure route and view_manager in module/config/module_config

```
  'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'Test' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
```